# Error in LibGDX: JNI ERROR (app bug): non-zero capacity for NULL pointer: 80000

Tags: java-native-interface, libgdx, dalvik

I have come across a new error in LibGdx which says non Zero Capacity for Null Pointer! What does this error mean?

> E/dalvikvm(28069): JNI ERROR (app bug): non-zero capacity for NULL pointer: 80000

Comment: Please add more of the dalivk log from this process.  There should be a backtrace that will pin-point which module has a bad error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is coming from `NewDirectByteBuffer` at line 2725 (of this copy of) Jni.cpp: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/3a7af00/vm/Jni.cpp

Some native code is trying to initialize an NIO DirectByteBuffer, and its passing in an initial size of 80,000 and a NULL pointer.  Since that does not make sense (the pointer should be non-NULL) an exception is thrown.  The pointer is most likely NULL because the allocation of the 80,000 bytes failed, most likely because your app has run out of memory, or because memory has become so fragmented, the 80k isn't available contiguously.

Technically, there is a small bug in the caller's code.  It should probably have thrown a more direct-to-the-point `OutOfMemoryError`, but the idea and the end result are the same.

Since 80k isn't very big, the statistically likely situation is that you have a memory leak (likely of this very object).

If you have a backtrace from the dalvik log, it may help pin-point where this particular error is coming from.  This would be handy for fixing the `OutOfMemoryError` bug (it could be in Libgdx, or in box2d, or in any of the native libraries used by Android, its impossible to say without more detail).  However, the real root of the problem is your memory leak.  Use the Eclipse DDMS heap tracking tools to figure out where that problem is coming from.

Comment: Please check the other question I have posted..I have posted the Dalvik log there. Help me out. Thanks!

Comment: @ChandrasekharMalladi you can edit existing questions to add or update information.  No need to ask a new question.